# Gradle counterpart to Maven archetype?

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-archetype

What is the Gradle counterpart to Maven archetypes? How can I give other Gradle users a template for the file and directory layout for a new project?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [build init plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html):

```
~$ mkdir newproj
~$ cd newproj
~/newproj$ gradle init --type java-library
```

At the moment (May 2023, Gradle 8.1) the following types are supported:

- pom
- basic
- java-application
- java-gradle-plugin
- java-library
- kotlin-application
- kotlin-gradle-plugin
- kotlin-library
- groovy-application
- groovy-gradle-plugin
- groovy-library
- scala-application
- scala-library

Comment: Seems to be renamed in 1.9 to "init-build" plugin, see http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.9/userguide/userguide_single.html#build_init_plugin

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34856834/create-custom-build-init-type-for-gradle-build-init-plugin

Comment: Unlike that useless plugin mentioned by others, this actually works.

Comment: it would be good if there was a way to list them from the command line. Also, this is a very small list compared to maven archetypes. I was hoping for something for graal VM projects, jar with dependencies etc.

Answer (score 9):

Gradle doesn't support this (yet). There's a open [feature request](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1289) opened already.

Comment: the jira says its fixed

Comment: So... do we have some news here?

Answer (score 9):

There is no gradle counterpart as far as I know. However following the steps given below is enough for most cases:

- Generate project with maven and your selection of maven archetype.
- Convert the maven project to gradle project. You can do that by executing the below command in the directory where your master pom.xml is located:

```
gradle init
```

It is supposed to work with all basic maven archetypes.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862275/how-to-convert-a-maven-build-to-gradle

Answer (score 3):

While this is not yet supported by Gradle, the [gradle:templates plugin](https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-templates) looks promising:

Answer (score 3):

**Gradle don't support build-in archetype-like feature**, but you can use plug-in named [Gradle templates](https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-templates)

*Read more:*
[Does gradle have Maven archetype-like functionality?](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/does-gradle-have-maven-archetype-like-functionality/3831)
[Gradle archetypes issue](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1387)

Answer (score 3):

I'm been looking for this feature as well, and found that it's a little bit complicated to have a complex project template to work with https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-templates.

So I created this plugin, it's quite similar with the Maven archetype function.
https://github.com/orctom/gradle-archetype-plugin/

Comment: Hey @Hao, I saw your plugin, but I can't figure out how to create my custom archetype

Answer (score 2):

Looks like solution is available now: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.orctom.archetype

Comment: I had a look and it's not clear how you specify a template.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using the spring framework under Linux: 
You could use http://start.spring.io/ 
or alternatively install [Spring CLI](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-installing-the-cli)

```
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

$ sdk install springboot

$ spring --version
Spring Boot v1.3.5.RELEASE

$ spring init --build gradle --name test --groupId com.test
Using service at https://start.spring.io
Content saved to 'demo.zip'

$ unzip demo.zip
```

Comment: This was not the qiestion

Answer (score 1):

You can create generators for [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), or use existing non-official ones such as [JHipster](http://www.jhipster.tech/). As an example there is the [java-gradle generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-java-gradle):

> 1. `npm install -g yo`
> 2. Install module globally: `npm install -g generator-java-gradle`
> 3. Generate project with: `yo java-gradle`

Comment: Generators still seem active, daily updates on many: http://yeoman.io/generators/. Not sure about yeoman core itself...