# How to convert a Maven build to Gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle

I know I should be working with my `build.gradle` and `init.gradle` files but I don't know what to write or how to point to my project folder with the `pom.xml` file.

Comment: If you're completely new to coding, I wouldn't recommend using Gradle as it requires you to define your builds in Groovy code.  You should go through some basic Groovy, Maven and Gradle tutorials before posting questions that are too vague to answer.

Comment: unfortunately, I need a proof of concept in the very near future. I guess a better question would be, how would one go about converting a maven project to gradle.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The first step is to run `gradle init` in the directory containing the (master) POM. This will convert the Maven build to a Gradle build, generating a `settings.gradle` file and one or more `build.gradle` files. For simpler Maven builds, this is all you need to do. For more complex Maven builds, it may be necessary to manually add functionality on the Gradle side that couldn't be converted automatically.

https://guides.gradle.org/migrating-from-maven/

Comment: Hey Thanks! My build failed due to this error: A problem occurred evaluating project ':DBSupport'.
> Could not find method providedCompile() for arguments [project ':Core:Platform
'] on project ':DBSupport'. 

Any idea what that means?

Comment: There should be a comment in the generated `build.gradle` that explains what it means.

Comment: Yes, there was this:     compile(group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version:'1.0.1') {
       /* This dependency was originally in the Maven provided scope, but the project was not of type war.
       This behavior is not yet supported by Gradle, so this dependency has been converted to a compile dependency.
       Please review and delete this closure when resolved. */

Comment: If you need help with this, search for `gradle provided scope` here or on http://forums.gradle.org. It's a common question.

Comment: I had to explicitly add " apply plugin: 'war' " to my converted Maven war project (even though my pom.xml had  <packaging>war</packaging>), in order for "providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api' ... " to work

Comment: Which Gradle version? If I'm not mistaken, recent Gradle versions will do this automatically.

Comment: In case you have a pom.xml from the maven project and like to move the dependencies into Gradle, you may want to use: https://sagioto.github.io/maven2gradle/

Answer (score 0):

as Peter Niederwieser said:

> For more complex Maven builds, it may be necessary to manually add
>   functionality on the Gradle side that couldn't be converted
>   automatically.

although you have to write some parts manually by your self. there is an online service that may be an useful tool For complex Maven builds. maven2gradle  is a project on github which can convert online dependencies element automatically from maven to gradle scripts.
for  using it,

1. get to [maven2gradle](http://sagioto.github.io/maven2gradle/) . URL
2. open and select contains of your maven file.
3. Paste your maven dependencies on the text box in that web page (with
   or without the dependencies root element).
4. click Convert button.

for more information  http://sagioto.github.io/maven2gradle/