# Gradle dependency - class not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a Gradle project in IntelliJ.

I added this dependency to Maven dependencies list

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
        <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
        <version>4.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When I try to compile my code using `gradlew build` I receive this compilation error:

```
gradlew build
:compileJava                                                                                                  
....java:5: error: package org.imgscalr does not exist
import org.imgscalr.Scalr;  
                   ^        
....java:52: error: cannot find symbol
                    BufferedImage thumbnail = Scalr.resize(image, 150);
                                              ^
  symbol:   variable Scalr  
  location: class PlaceController
2 errors                    
:compileJava FAILED         

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:       
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

What is happening?

After adding the dependency inside maven file, IntelliJ automatically downloads the file and imports it where it is needed. By doing this, the error from the IDE, that says tahat Scalr could not be found, dissapears.

Comment: Sorry you are talking about a maven dependency but writing about gradle? What are really using?

Comment: The project is a gradle project and I am using gradle. But inside it, it also has a `pom.xml` file.

Comment: gradle doesn't use pom.xml files. It uses build.gradle files.

Comment: Then why Intellij created that pom.xml? Also why is it reacting when I make changes inside pom.xml?

Comment: @tzortzik probably because you told IntelliJ that your project was a Maven project, even though you're building it wth Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

You should be covering this in your `build.gradle` file instead.  Here's an example of how it would look.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2'
}
```

If you were looking to do a wholesale conversion from Maven to Gradle, you'd have to [convert your POMs over first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20862275/1079354) and iron out any bugs that may have resulted due to the conversion.