# Converting custom maven pom config to custom build.gradle config

Tags: java, maven, gradle, plugins

I currently have a task to move my project from maven to gradle and was wondering how I might implement execution of a custom plugin:

My PoM:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>myproj.tool</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
          <dictFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/project7.xml</dictFile>
          <packaging>custom.api</packaging>
          <fieldPackage>custom.api.field</fieldPackage>
          <!-- optional configs schemaDirectory, outputDirectory, decimal, orderedFields -->
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

So far my build.gradle file

```
group = 'myproj.tool.plugin'
description = ''
dependencies {
  compile project('quickfixj-api')
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert maven pom to gradle build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862275/how-to-convert-a-maven-build-to-gradle)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but the title is misleading--this is about custom plugins, which will have to be rewritten.