# Gradle to auto generate project

Tags: maven, gradle

I am new to gradle, and wondering if gradle has the similar mechanism as maven to generate project. like `mvn archetype-generate`

Also, if I have a meven project, is there a way to auto convert it to gradle?

Comment: Autogenerate a project from what?  There's automation around setting up the Gradle wrapper: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:wrapper_generation

Comment: see revised question

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862275/how-to-convert-a-maven-build-to-gradle