# Create custom Build init type - for Gradle Build Init Plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm fairly new to gradle and I would like to create a custom type for with the Gradle Init Plugin. Moreover, I'd like to be able to do something like:

`gradle init --type jsp-library`

This would generate a project directory with the same structure as a Java web application (webapp, stylesheets, etc...). Yes, I have read [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html), and I know that only a limited amount of types are available. I just want to know if someone has or knows of some sort of work around for the time being.

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1686 is for 3rd party types in the `init` plugin.

Comment: I can't believe there is still no standardized way to achieve this. I'm still copying and pasting for my GraalVM projects, or even jar-with-dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. There are 3rd party plugins that allow you to create custom templates and generate new projects from templates. For instance, see: https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-templates
2. Use maven to generate a project from archetype and then use gradle init to convert it to gradle project.
3. Modify the init plugin yourself from [source](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/6277a4dc70fbeea83c111e75c95ba851d1e56ffc/subprojects/build-init/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/buildinit/plugins/internal/BuildInitTypeIds.java) to add more init types.