# dependencies syntax in gradle (closed)

Tags: gradle

I am trying to understand Gradle.I got this in my code

`testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.9.0'`

It works.

I wanted to understand the concepts.

Comment: Your title is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524790/gradle-counterpart-to-maven-archetype . Your question is not related and not clear.

Comment: If you want to understand Gradle, read the Userguide and if not enough, read the DSL doc and if not enough read the JavaDoc and if not enough read the code. If you have a concrete question, state it here. What you wrote to far is not nearly a quesiton at all. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to improve your question.

Comment: @Vampire, thank you. You scared the hell out of me. Yes, will do. This is my second question on stack so far. But will respect the expectations here. Thanks again.

Comment: So how about an edit of your question? Otherwise it needs to be closed because it is unclear.

Comment: Please read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html and https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html. There all possible syntaxes are well documented.

Comment: Thank you.  @Vampire, yes, I started reading documentations. Was migrating something and got a question and suddenly posted it. But you could please close it. It was dumb. :(.  But will be mindful now on that people put effort to answer my questions and I have ask after my research.

Comment: I'm just a user like you, I cannot close your question. But you could delete it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote dependencies in Gradle follow the same format as Maven.   Dependencies are structured as follows

```
compile 'group:name:version'
```

or this alternative syntax:

```
compile group: 'xxx', name: 'xxxxx', version: 'xxxx'
```

The same syntax is valid also for tests.

```
dependencies { 
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.9.0" 
}
```

or

```
dependencies { 
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.9.0'
}
```