# Is there any archetype or template to create a gradle project like maven archetype?

Tags: gradle

I want to create my gradle project with a template.
We know, we can create and init a maven project with maven archetype like:

```html
mvn archetype:generate 
     -DgroupId=com.project 
     -DartifactId=project-test
     -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Is the any archetype for gradle init a project?
PS:
I know gradle init -type java-application.
But how to build a type for myself?

Comment: It seems that more or less `init` might be what you're looking for: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html

Comment: You means use the `gradle init --type java-application`? But can I customize this type?The command will create an empty java project, I want a java project of my initialization code of my company. Please, tks!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524790/gradle-counterpart-to-maven-archetype

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle counterpart to Maven archetype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524790/gradle-counterpart-to-maven-archetype)