# gradle recipe/archetype/generators for multi-modules kotlin nodejs backend and reactjs frontend

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-js

I'm missing or looking for is something similar to a maven archetype or a yoeman generator.  I need a starter project with best practices with the basic plumbing and scaffolding in place which i can learn from and build upon.

I'm experimenting with kotlin-js.  To be clear, i'm fairly **new to Kotlin**, i have a **decent experience with nodejs** on the server side and am a **reactjs novice**.  i'm working on a trivial project that will require some rest services and a trivial android app.  I was hoping to do all my coding in Kotlin to help with the learning process.  Some of you will want to deter me from doing the JS part in Kotlin i'm sure but i very much want to give this a try as i have some time to figure these things out.  I am willing to make some mistakes but i would love to standardize on Kotlin as my language for all of my work (if at all practical).

Since i want to try and use Kotlin for all of this, i thought it would be good to also use Kotlin DSL for gradle.  I am struggling to find a good template to start with.  i see a number of git projects that set up single or multi module vanilla JS or node JS apps but most don't go beyond hello world.  More than the depth of the actual functional areas of code, what really bothers me is that the gradle configuration for each of these are so different from each other and i really don't know which one makes for a good template from a best practices point of view.

Here are my high level goals for setting up the overall project.  Could even be more than one project eventually.

I use IntelliJ IDEA Community as my IDE

- use Kotlin DSL in gradle scripts (.kts) to help further my knowledge on koltin. i prefer not to invest in Groovy right now.  though i have some experience on groovy from the past

need multi module project setup that will be composed of

- some common modules, say to make some part of my code re-usable and
  the project modular in general
- one of the common modules would be an api module (express perhaps) that would be consumed by
- an android app
- a react front end

Any advise in this area would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your question is. I know the feeling, I started kotlinjs a year ago and you stand in front of a mountain of questions. I would suggest to amend your post with a least a couple of them if you want clear helpful answers. Like how does the setup work? What gradle configuration do I need? How do I write tests? And so furth... (if that is what you want to know)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524790/gradle-counterpart-to-maven-archetype